Action of monodromy on the $p$-adic period domain in Lawrence-Venkatesh
In here, I asked various questions related to Lawrence and Venkatesh's work on the Mordell-Weil conjecture, which failed to receive any answers.
This is my attempt to try and focus the question.
In their paper, Lawrence and Venkatesh construct a function they call the $p$-adic period map, denoted $\Phi_p: \Omega_x\longrightarrow \mathcal{M}$, where $x\in X(K)$ is a $K$-rational point on a $p$-adic curve $X$, $\Omega_x$ is its associated residue disk, and $\mathcal{M}$ is a certain Grassmanian.
In the background, they have a smooth proper fibration $Y\longrightarrow X$, called a Kodaira-Parshin family, such that the fibre above every point $x'\in \Omega_x$ is a certain curve $Y_{x'}$ of a fixed positive genus $g$, so that $H^1_{dR}(Y_{x'}, K)$ is a $2g$-dimensional $K$-vector space.
The map $\Phi_p$ assocaites to a point $x'\in \Omega_x$ the Hodge filtration on $H^1_{dR}(Y_{x'}, K)$, viewed as a point of $\mathcal{M}$. A particular simple example to keep in mind is when $X = \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0,1,\infty\}$, in which case $Y\longrightarrow X$ may be taken to be the Legendre family; where the fibre above every $x'\in\Omega_x$ is an elliptic curve $Y_{x'}$, $H^1_{dR}(Y_{x'}, K)$ is $2$-dimensional, the (non-trivial) piece of the Hodge filtration is $1$-dimensional, hence $\mathcal{M}$ may be taken to be $\mathbb{P}^1_K$, the moduli of lines in $2$-dimensional $K$-space.
In their paper, they say, without proof, that if $\Gamma$ is the monodromy group, i.e. the image of $\rho_x: \pi_1^{\text{et}}(\overline{X}, \overline{x})\longrightarrow \text{End}(H^1_{\text{et}}(\overline{Y_x}, \mathbb{Q}_p))$, then $\Gamma$ has a natural action on $\mathcal{M}$. Can anyone explain how this action is defined?
